# How to write let statement inside an 'if' and 'loop' statements in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, jdeveloper

I want to iterate over an element to take the position of the element having the closest date to current time, however the code is not working with a syntax error `let is unexpected`
code:

```
  for $pos in 1 to fn:count($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord)
               where fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos]/per1:LeaveFlag)!='ShortLeave'
               and fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos]/per1:LeaveStartDate) >= fn:current-date()
              
              return if (op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos + 1]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()) < op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()))
               then
               let $count:=$pos +1  return
               else
               let $count:=$pos return
```

I would appreciate any help!! thanks :)

Comment: How many `count`s do you want? One value? Or as many as there are `$req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord`? Where do you want to use the `$count` variable? It sounds more like you want `for $pos in ... where ... let $count := if (...) then $pos + 1 else $pos return some-expression-using-$count` but it is not clear from your single expression what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also note that (at the least the current version of XQuery) has an `at $pos` clause e.g. `for $record at $pos in $req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the if/else you have started a FLWOR with a `let` and you have a `return` that isn't returning anything. So, to complete your FLWOR you need to return something. Presumably, the `$count`.

```
return 
  if (op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos + 1]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()) < op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()))
  then
    let $count:=$pos +1  return $count
  else
    let $count:=$pos return $count
```

But if you are just going to return that `$count` then don't bother letting a variable:

```
if (op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos + 1]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()) < op:subtract-dates(fn:data($req/ns1:Body/ns1:SpecialLeaveEnrollRecord[$pos]/per1:LeaveStartDate), fn:current-date()))
then
  $pos +1  
else
  $pos
```

Comment: I just want to know if I use the first option you gave me does the value of count overwrite during the for loop, noting that I want overwrite to occur as I want to save the index in that count to use in the code as an index. Thank you!